# Saving a new Base URL to a test suite

Tags: url, selenium, ide, radix

I created a test suite that has 57 different tests in it for one of my environments. Now, I would like to implement the test suite to 10 other nearly identical environments. I have already done a dry run in the second environment and it runs well, the issue is that I need to go through and manually change the base url for each individual test every time I open the suite.

Ideally, Id like to have "Environment 1 test suite", "Environment 2 test suite", etc. When I click on a test suite, it opens the tests with the base url for the corresponding environment. I tried saving the modified suite. I tried saving the individual copies of the test cases. I cant figure out how to get the new copy of test cases to stop reverting to the original base url when I close and reopen the suite.

Comment: I appreciate the help on this answer.

Being a self taught manual tester with no previous dev or automation experience, a lot of answers ive found have gone right over my head. 

The "for dummies" solution I found was to open each HTML file in textpad and modify the base URL manually.

Next step is to find a program that will allow me to find and replace in multiple html files in one go.

Comment: Multiple HTML files will require more maintenance - each time you add/modify a test you will have to edit all files. Anyways, you can use [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to find and replace in multiple files by using its 'Find in Files' feature.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a properties file. Provide the URL in a variable and then use this variable to set the Base URL in your scripts.

To add a properties file, create a text file such as `TestData.js` containing your base URL:

```
baseUrl="http://www.boogiesite.com"
```

Now add this file to Selenium IDE using IDE > Options > Options >  General tab > Selenium IDE Extensions > browse and select file TestData.js.

Reference:
http://selftechy.com/2011/06/30/parameterization-of-tests-in-selenium-ide

A similar previous SO question provides more answers:

[selenium IDE - how can I change the Base URL for all my tests in one go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689894/selenium-ide-how-can-i-change-the-base-url-for-all-my-tests-in-one-go)